# DataDog: Browser based synthetic test: Clicking on link open new tab

Tags: datadog

I am trying to write a browser based synthetic test in DataDog.

One test step requires clicking on a link (say on screen A) that opens a new tab with certain details (say screen B). I am able to record the test, just fine. However, execution fails with DataDog showing the screenshot of the first tab  i.e. the screen A.

Question:

- is DataDog screen recorder capable of capturing a "open in new tab" action and then switching to the new tab ?
- if yes, is there a resolution/workaround to the situation ? it is possible that I am not doing this right, in which, I will really benefit from some pointers ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Once your new tab opens, you should be able to use a [Subtest](https://docs.datadoghq.com/synthetics/browser_tests/advanced_options/#subtests) for the [new tab/window](https://docs.datadoghq.com/synthetics/browser_tests/actions/?tab=testanelementontheactivepage#subtests).